# Delete all records but one that are fetched by a given query

Tags: oracle, duplicates, sql-delete, record

I have two tables `reminder` and `reminder_users`, between these tables there is a foreign key constraint and `reminder_users` are the child records. What I want to do is to delete several redundant rows in these tow tables. What I managed to do so far is to find the redundant rows with the following query:

```
select r.name, r.remark, u.user_id, u.deadline , count (*)
from reminder r 
inner join reminder_users u on r.id = u.reminder_id 
and u.user_id = u.user_id 
and u.deadline = u.deadline having count(*)> 1
group by r.name, r.remark, u.user_id, u.deadline
```

So the redundant rows are tied with the foreign key `id` and the child records have the same `user_id` and the same `deadline`, and the parent records have the same name and the same remark.

The `having count` clause point out the rows, that are redundant, but I want do keep one of the records so that having count > 1 is not true any more, so i can not use this clause in a delete-query. Also in order to be able to delete the rows from reminder, first the child data from reminder_users have to be deleted.

I guess that it should somehow be possible with the usage of the `rowid` and something like a `select max (rowid)`, but i have no further ideas how to structure the delete-query.

Any help is much appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. You can [delete duplicate rows](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-find-and-delete-duplicate-rows-with-sql) by removing all those where their `rowid` is not one returned by the subquery:

```
delete reminder 
where  rowid not in ( 
  select min ( r.rowid )
  from reminder r 
  inner join reminder_users u 
  on r.id = u.reminder_id 
  and u.user_id = u.user_id 
  and u.deadline = u.deadline 
  group by r.name, r.remark, u.user_id, u.deadline
)
```

There's no need for the `having` clause in the subquery.

Note: this assumes that there's a row in `reminder_users` for every `reminder`. If this isn't the case, this will also remove the reminders without a user as the subquery will not return them.